# Getting Error while Training using template https://github.com/apache/incubator-predictionio-template-text-classifier.git

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, predictionio

i am new to PredictionIo. I begin to test some templates. When i use Text-classification and i do `pio train` 
I have the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$implicits$.rddToDataFrameHolder(Lorg/apache/spark/rdd/RDD;Lscala/reflect/api/TypeTags$TypeTag;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameHolder;
at org.example.textclassification.LRAlgorithm.train(LRAlgorithm.scala:37)
at org.example.textclassification.LRAlgorithm.train(LRAlgorithm.scala:19)
at org.apache.predictionio.controller.P2LAlgorithm.trainBase(P2LAlgorithm.scala:49)
at org.apache.predictionio.controller.Engine$$anonfun$18.apply(Engine.scala:690)
at org.apache.predictionio.controller.Engine$$anonfun$18.apply(Engine.scala:690)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
at org.apache.predictionio.controller.Engine$.train(Engine.scala:690)
at org.apache.predictionio.controller.Engine.train(Engine.scala:176)
at org.apache.predictionio.workflow.CoreWorkflow$.runTrain(CoreWorkflow.scala:67)
at org.apache.predictionio.workflow.CreateWorkflow$.main(CreateWorkflow.scala:251)
at org.apache.predictionio.workflow.CreateWorkflow.main(CreateWorkflow.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:743)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:187)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

my environment 
PredictionIO: Version0.11
Spark : version 2.1.1 
elasticsearch : 5.3.2
templates : https://github.com/apache/incubator-predictionio/

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention that particular spark version in the build.sbt and if that does not solve the issue. Then please provide the template Github link and mention any other changes that you have done in the template.